# How to clean readline data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have `'\n'` and `'\r'` in my readline data which is coming from Microcontroller. I have tried to clean them through the following code but still I  have `b''` in every line. Is there any way to remove it completely from the data ?

```
bs = ser.readline()
bs = bs.replace(b'\n', b' ').replace(b'\r', b' ')
print(bs)
```

Answer (score 3):

`b''` means it is sequence of bytes not string, you can `.decode()`(utf-8 by default) it to convert it to python string. also use `.strip()` without arguments, it will remove leading and trailing whitespaces from the string.

```
ser.readline().decode().strip()
```

If `'\n'` and `'\r'` exists in the middle of the string you can use either `.replace()` or `.translate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

`b''` in your string shows it's a Bytes literals. you need to decode it into [utf-8 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

```
print(bs.decode('utf-8'))
```